# Problem using grep to specify process IDs for I/O priority setting

Tags: bash, awk, io, grep, ionice

I want to set highest I/O priority using ionice for processes with specific name (farmer and harvest)
Please help check what is wrong with my script it's not working

```
sudo ionice -c 1 -n 0 -p $(ps -ef | grep farmer | awk '{print $2}')
sudo ionice -c 1 -n 0 -p $(ps -ef | grep harvest | awk '{print $2}')
```

I got the error `"ionice: ioprio_set failed: No such process"` even though these processes exist

Answer (score 0):

Use `pgrep`.

```
sudo ionice -c 1 -n 0 -p $(pgrep farmer)
sudo ionice -c 1 -n 0 -p $(pgrep harvest)
```